How to place 2 graphs with subplots side by side in Python?
I would like to plot positive and negative word charts for each category together on the same grid. To achieve that, I'm using plt.subplot(). I'm using for loop to plot graphs for all the categories. My question is: how can I place two categories' graphs (positive and negative charts for each category on the same grid) in 1 row?
for category in results_df['Category'].unique():
    plt.figure(figsize=(6, 4))

    plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
    subset_positive = results_df[(results_df['Category'] == category) & (results_df['Sentiment'] == 'Positive')]
    subset_positive = subset_positive.sort_values(by='Frequency', ascending=False)
    ax = sns.barplot(x='Frequency', y='Word', data=subset_positive, color=sns.color_palette('muted')[2])
    ax.set(ylabel = '', xlabel='')
    plt.title('Positive Words')

    plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
    subset_negative = results_df[(results_df['Category'] == category) & (results_df['Sentiment'] == 'Negative')]
    subset_negative = subset_negative.sort_values(by='Frequency', ascending=False)
    ax = sns.barplot(x='Frequency', y='Word', data=subset_negative, color=sns.color_palette('muted')[0])
    ax.set(ylabel = '', xlabel='')
    plt.title('Negative Words')

    plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.5, top = 0.85)
    plt.suptitle(f'Most Frequent Words in Comments for {category}')
    plt.show()

I tried the following code
categories = results_df['Category'].unique()

fig, axs = plt.subplots(7, 2, figsize=(20, 35))
axs = axs.flatten()

for i, category in enumerate(categories):
    subset_positive = results_df[(results_df['Category'] == category) & (results_df['Sentiment'] == 'Positive')]
    subset_positive = subset_positive.sort_values(by='Frequency', ascending=False)
    ax = axs[i * 2]
    sns.barplot(x='Frequency', y='Word', data=subset_positive, color=sns.color_palette('muted')[2], ax=ax)
    ax.set_title(f'Positive Words - {category}')

    subset_negative = results_df[(results_df['Category'] == category) & (results_df['Sentiment'] == 'Negative')]
    subset_negative = subset_negative.sort_values(by='Frequency', ascending=False)
    ax = axs[i * 2 + 1]
    sns.barplot(x='Frequency', y='Word', data=subset_negative, color=sns.color_palette('muted')[0], ax=ax)
    ax.set_title(f'Negative Words - {category}')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()


But this created all the separate charts on the same graph. Is it possible to keep the graphs separated but place them side by side (2 in one row)?

you can use plt.subplots to create a grid of subplots.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

categories = results_df['Category'].unique()
num_categories = len(categories)

# Create subplots with `num_categories` rows and 2 columns
fig, axs = plt.subplots(num_categories, 2, figsize=(20, num_categories * 5))

for i, category in enumerate(categories):
    # Positive words subplot
    subset_positive = results_df[(results_df['Category'] == category) & (results_df['Sentiment'] == 'Positive')]
    subset_positive = subset_positive.sort_values(by='Frequency', ascending=False)
    sns.barplot(x='Frequency', y='Word', data=subset_positive, color=sns.color_palette('muted')[2], ax=axs[i, 0])
    axs[i, 0].set_title(f'Positive Words - {category}')
    axs[i, 0].set_ylabel('')
    axs[i, 0].set_xlabel('')

    # Negative words subplot
    subset_negative = results_df[(results_df['Category'] == category) & (results_df['Sentiment'] == 'Negative')]
    subset_negative = subset_negative.sort_values(by='Frequency', ascending=False)
    sns.barplot(x='Frequency', y='Word', data=subset_negative, color=sns.color_palette('muted')[0], ax=axs[i, 1])
    axs[i, 1].set_title(f'Negative Words - {category}')
    axs[i, 1].set_ylabel('')
    axs[i, 1].set_xlabel('')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.95)
fig.suptitle('Most Frequent Words in Comments for Each Category', fontsize=16)
plt.show()


This separates positive and negative charts into two different graphs and plots them side by side. I would like to keep positive and negative charts in one grid and plot one more grid (with positive and negative charts for another category) in the same row.
